# Why are Nightwatch.js tests failing on CircleCI?

Tags: nightwatch.js, circleci

I have a simple smoketest set up using Nightwatch.js. They pass locally, but they're failing on CircleCI.

**Source Code:**

```
const WAIT = 1000;
const NODE_PORT = process.env.NODE_PORT || 3000;

module.exports = {
  'Smoketest' (browser) {
    browser
      .url(`http://localhost:${NODE_PORT}/`)
      .waitForElementVisible('body', WAIT)
      .pause(300)
      .assert.containsText('body', 'Client render')
      .end();
  }
};
```

**Local output:**

```
> cross-env NODE_PORT=3000 NODE_PATH=source babel-node source/test/e2e.js

Running with config:
{ logDir: '/Users/eric/Dropbox/dev/react-easy-universal/reports',
  reportDir: '/Users/eric/Dropbox/dev/react-easy-universal/reports/test-e2e',
  nightwatchConfig: '/Users/eric/Dropbox/dev/react-easy-universal/nightwatch.json',
  webpackConfig: '/Users/eric/Dropbox/dev/react-easy-universal/webpack.config.js',
  port: '3000',
  server: [Object] }

[Smoketest] Test Suite
======================

Running:  Smoketest
 ✔ Element <body> was visible after 58 milliseconds.
 ✔ Testing if element <body> contains text: "Client render".

OK. 2 assertions passed. (2.831s)
```

**Failing CircleCI output:**

```
REPORT_DIR=${CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS} LOG_DIR=${CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS} npm run test:e2e -s
Running with config:
{ logDir: '/tmp/circle-artifacts.ddv7oJ3',
  reportDir: '/tmp/circle-junit.hhJgS6N',
  nightwatchConfig: '/home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/nightwatch.json',
  webpackConfig: '/home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/webpack.config.js',
  port: '3000',
  server: [Object] }

[Smoketest] Test Suite
======================

Running:  Smoketest
 ✔ Element <body> was visible after 85 milliseconds.
 ✖ Testing if element <body> contains text: "Client render".  - expected "Client render" but got: Untitled
    at Object.Smoketest (smoketest.js:10:15)
    at Module.call (/home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/module.js:63:34)
    at /home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/testcase.js:97:29
    at _fulfilled (/home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/home/ubuntu/react-easy-universal/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)

FAILED:  1 assertions failed and 1 passed (3.242s)

----------------------------------------------------
TEST FAILURE: 1 assertions failed, 1 passed (3.543s)
 ✖ smoketest
   - Smoketest

Testing if element <body> contains text: "Client render". - Expected "Client render" but got: "Untitled" REPORT_DIR=${CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS} LOG_DIR=${CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS} npm run test:e2e -s returned exit code 1
```

Initially, the browser starts with some rendered output from the server. The title from the server render is set to "Untitled". Then some JavaScript loads and runs in the client, and the client render happens, changing the text to "Client render". This test is intended to ensure that the client render is working as expected.

Here's the `nightwatch.json`:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["source/test/functional/browser"],
  "output_folder" : "./reports/test-e2e",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "server_path" : "",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },

    "chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've suspected it could be a race condition, thinking that the assertion runs before CircleCI has a chance to load and process the JavaScript, so I've tried inserting a pause before the assertion.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also this issue and it looks like (still need to recheck) I found a solution.

Make sure you you have as last code in each of your test this at the end.

browser.end();